What does the double covering in the Dirac equation have to do with that of $SO(3)$ by $SU(2)$?
The Dirac spinors themselves are certainly more than a mere double cover of $SO(1,3)$, as can easily be seen from the fact that a Dirac spinor has 8 degrees of freedom whereas a Lorentz transformation has only 6.  Even if you make it a unit spinor, it still has an extra degree of freedom.  In the spacetime algebra representation of a Dirac spinor as
$$\psi = R(\rho e^{i\beta})^{\frac12}$$
with $R$ being a rotor, I think we can say that the rotors themselves are already an exact double cover of the Lorentz transforms, as $-R$ effects the same transformation as $R$ when applied via conjugation.  Yet it's also true that when you continuously transform the Dirac equation itself, the spinor wavefunction requires precisely two full rotations to return to its original sign.
Meanwhile, the exact double cover of $SO(3)$ by $SU(2)$, with the latter being isomorphic to unit 3D spinors/rotors, is often used to explain double covering by spinors.  But what is the connection between these two cases: on the one hand, the double covering under transformation of something that is actually more than a double cover of the rotation group of the 4D space, and on the other, the perfect double-covering of the 3D space?

Hestenes modifies the Dirac equation in order to identify the Dirac spinor's 8 real components with those of the even spacetime algebra. I think that's wrong, because it's incompatible with the fact that a Dirac spinor is two Weyl spinors of 4 real components each. But I can still answer your question, just talking about the even spacetime algebra in place of Dirac spinors.
In $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ space(time) dimensions, the dimension of the even real Clifford algebra minus that of its embedded spin group is $1,1,1,2,6,17,43,100,\ldots$ (A014833). One of the extra dimensions is just a real scale factor. It's in four dimensions that other degrees of freedom first show up and things get uglier. That's why the Clifford-algebraic version of $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spin}{Spin} \Spin(3)$ is "perfect" and $\Spin(1,3)$ isn't. Fortunately there is only one extra DOF in 4 dimensions.
$C\ell^+(\mathbb R^{1,3})$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb C)$, and you can show* that $\det(A) = A \widetilde A = \widetilde A A$, where $\det$ is the matrix determinant and $\widetilde{\phantom A}$ is the Clifford reversal. Note that the determinant is a complex number; $i$ in the Clifford algebra is the pseudoscalar. $\mathrm{Spin}(1,3) \subset C\ell^+(\mathbb R^{1,3})$ is isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb C) \subset M_2(\mathbb C)$, so the embedded $\mathrm{Spin}(1,3)$ is in Clifford-algebraic terms $\{ R \mathbin{|} R \widetilde R = 1 \}$. I think this set is the same as Hestenes's set of rotors.
* It follows easily from the identities $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \mathrm{tr}(A) = A + \widetilde A$ and $\det(A) = \frac12(\tr(A)^2 - \tr(A^2))$.
Given that, it's easy to see that any invertible element of the algebra can be written as the product of a $\mathrm{Spin}(1,3)$ element and a complex scalar. The magnitude of the scalar is the uninteresting real scaling factor. What's left is $e^{iβ/2}$. The effect of that extra degree of freedom on a vector is $$e^{iβ/2} \, \mathbf v \, e^{-iβ/2} = e^{iβ} \, \mathbf v = \mathbf v \cos β + i\mathbf v \sin β$$ i.e., it "rotates" the vector into its Hodge dual. I'm not convinced that this operation doesn't have some physical significance, but if it does, I don't know what it is.
(Incidentally, the constraint $R \widetilde R = 1$ applies in any number of dimensions. The number of extra degrees of freedom not eliminated by that constraint is $0,0,0,0,0,1,7,28,84,211,\ldots$ (A014833 minus A038503). In 6+0 dimensions, which is important in GUTs, the one extra DOF is the phase of the matrix determinant, which is not constrained by $R \widetilde R = 1$ unlike in 3+1 dimensions.)

I've been confused by this too, for years, and thank you for noticing that it has something to do with the Hodge dual. The components of a vectorial quantity can be contravariant, covariant, or invariant. Hestenes had chosen to represent everything in invariant, in which case there is an additional symmetry between physical vectors and one-forms. This is really unphysical because contravariance and covariance is actually physical---only covariant components (energy and momentum) is conserved, by Noether's theorem.

My understanding is that, because the pseudoscalar in 4D is its own reverse, and because the timelike unit vector squares to -1, conjugation by a complex scalar actually has no effect on a vector.  Or maybe this is related to the Dirac spinor being two Weyl spinors?  Could you elaborate on this point?

@AdamHerbst I'm taking the position that the correct generalization of the rotor action $Rv\widetilde R$ is $xvx^{-1}$ (which is conjugation by definition), not $xv\widetilde x$, because only the former acts homomorphically on multivectors. In the full algebra that I had to use to define the action on a vector, "$i$" anticommutes with vectors, so $e^{iβ}$ isn't really a complex scalar in that context, even though I treated it as one in the rest of the answer.
